# Prestashop custom tab in Back Office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm developing a module for prestashop 1.5.3. I need to create a custom admin tab during the module installation. I make the install like this

```
public function install()
{
    if( (parent::install() == false)||(!$this->_createTab())  )
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And the _createTab method is:

```
private function _createTab()
{
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->id_parent = 7; // Modules tab
    $tab->class_name='AdminWarranty';
    $tab->module='fruitwarranty';
    $tab->name[(int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))] = $this->l('Warranty');
    $tab->active=1;
        if(!$tab->save()) return false;
return true;
}
```

And nothing happens.. What am I doing wrong.. and where to find good prestashop developer reference.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a custom tab for a module during installation you can use the following code.

**Note: I am considering a test module called News.**

```
private function _createTab()
{
    /* define data array for the tab  */
    $data = array(
                  'id_tab' => '', 
                  'id_parent' => 7, 
                  'class_name' => 'AdminNews', 
                  'module' => 'news', 
                  'position' => 1, 'active' => 1 
                 );

    /* Insert the data to the tab table*/
    $res = Db::getInstance()->insert('tab', $data);

    //Get last insert id from db which will be the new tab id
    $id_tab = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

   //Define tab multi language data
    $data_lang = array(
                     'id_tab' => $id_tab, 
                     'id_lang' => Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),
                     'name' => 'News'
                     );

    // Now insert the tab lang data
    $res &= Db::getInstance()->insert('tab_lang', $data_lang);

    return true;

} /* End of createTab*/
```

I hope the above code will help
Thanks

Comment: what is class_name in your case? can you give an example please?

Comment: The class_name is AdminNews in my case. You can change it to your class name AdminWarranty .

Comment: Yeah I Got It, but what is that class? what does it represents? can you show please a snippet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know, every tab at admin actually represents a class file. If you look at the controllers/admin/ then there you will see some controller classes, these are the classes associated with each tab at admin. This class provides all features at admin management side. Also please note that each controller class may have another class which we can call Model Class, which handles all database related and data related operations. Prestashop is loosly based on MVC pattern. for further studies please read http://www.programmingtunes.com/prestashop-1-5-features-for-developers-part-1-modules/ .

Comment: And also read http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module  and  http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html

Comment: What are you using $res for ? Considering you're always returning true...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm myself developing a PrestaShop module so in case someone lands here, the proper way.

For root tabs:

```
$rootTab = new Tab();
$rootTab->active = 1;
$rootTab->class_name = 'YourAdminControllerName';
$rootTab->name = array();
foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
    $rootTab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = $this->l("Root tab");
}
$rootTab->id_parent = 0; // No parent
$rootTab->module = $this->name;
$rootTab->add();
```

**Note for version 1.5:** When creating a root tab, the system will look for a YourAdminControllerName.gif in your module's folder as the tab icon. Also please note that root tabs don't work as links, despite them requiring a class_name.

For non-root tabs:

```
$tab = new Tab();
$tab->active = 1;
$tab->class_name = 'YourAdminControllerName';
$tab->name = array();
foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
    $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = $this->l("Non-root tab");
}
$tab->id_parent = $rootTab->id; // Set the root tab we just created as parent
$tab->module = $this->name;
$tab->add();
```

If you want to set an existing tab as parent, you can use the getIdFromClassName function. For example, in your case:

```
$tab->id_parent = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminModules');
```

The add() function returns false if it fails, so you can use it in the if() as you were trying to do with the save() function.

Sadly PrestaShop is by far the worst documented CMS system I've had to work with, and the only way to really code for it is reading code, so I hope it helps someone.